# Skipping HTML tag within Scrapy

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

I am scraping data using Scrapy (Python3) from a website and I would like to skip an <a> tag withing the source code because there are two and both have the same classes as you can see in the picture below:

[image]

I am trying the select the <a> tag that is highlighted in blue.

I'm using this: `response.xpath("//nav[@class='mp-PaginationControls-pagination']/a/@href").get()`, but that only let's me select the first <a> tag so it bugs after I'm on page two.

Here is the raw XML:

```
<div class="mp-PaginationControls mp-PaginationControls--new">
  <nav class="mp-PaginationControls-pagination">
    <a class="mp-TextLink mp-Button mp-Button--primary" href="/l/muziek-en-instrumenten/microfoons/">
      <span aria-hidden="true" class="mp-Button-icon mp-Button-icon--center mp-svg-arrow-left--inverse"></span>
    </a>
    <span class="mp-PaginationControls-pagination-pageList">
      <a class="mp-TextLink" href="/l/muziek-en-instrumenten/microfoons/">1</a>
      <span>2</span>
      <a class="mp-TextLink" href="/l/muziek-en-instrumenten/microfoons/p/3/">3</a>
      <span>...</span>
      <span>142</span>
    </span>
    <span class="mp-PaginationControls-pagination-amountOfPages">Pagina 2 van 142</span>
    <a class="mp-TextLink mp-Button mp-Button--primary" href="/l/muziek-en-instrumenten/microfoons/p/3/">
      <span aria-hidden="true" class="mp-Button-icon mp-Button-icon--center mp-svg-arrow-right--inverse"></span>
    </a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see from the XML you shared the second `a` has different `href` attribute value.
But since you want to get the `href`  value of it I guess you can't build your XPath based on it...
But below the `a` are `span` nodes, so you can find the parent `a` based on it.
As following:

```xml
response.xpath("//nav[@class='mp-PaginationControls-pagination']//a[./span[contains(@class,'mp-svg-arrow-right--inverse')]]/@href").get()
```